# Render different content in a scalable way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a use case where I want some pages to display a `<DefaultAppBar />` and some pages like 'settings' and 'edit profile' to display an `<EditableAppBar />` (where one is the main app bar and the other displays an 'X' icon and a checkmark icon to save changes)

**THE GOAL**  is to make this scalable for a team of devs down the line. *Ideally*, all they have to do is make a new Route, use the render prop on the Route and pass a Redux action that changes a piece of global state. The `<AppShell />` component then checks that piece of state and renders the appropriate app bar component. I would like to avoid having to dig through the directory (which is already quite large) and call the action from a componentWillMount() method.

**Temporary solution** is to write my Routes like this:
(`this.props.cantEdit` is the redux action being passed a const set to `true` or `false`

```
<Route
    exact
    path={profile}
    render={props => 
        <Profile candEdit={this.props.canEdit(editFalse)} {...props} />}
/>
<Route
    path={settings}
    render={props => 
        <UserSettings canEdit={this.props.canEdit(editTrue)} {...props} />}
/>
```

I know this isn't the greatest - passing a function CALL as props. But right now it's working and not causing any problems. Something along these lines would be great since the action is essentially being called by the Route. Again, the idea is that all a dev has to do is write a new route passing the action and variable, and the correct app bar component is displayed without having to dig into the specific component file to write the method.

Any advice/recommendations/different approaches is appreciated!

Comment: canEdit is a dispatcher or receiver? if it is a dispatcher, then you're going right way.

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact terminology, but 'this.props.canEdit()' is the action (so I assume the dispatcher since it's dispatched to the store?), and 'canEdit' is just the prop to use to house the action call - I'm not actually using 'canEdit' in either component. It's basically there so that 'this.props.canEdit()' will run when the corresponding route is visited.

Comment: so, you're at right path. what's the issue you face?

Comment: The app doesn't break, but It returns in error in the console: 
index.js:2178 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

and also just best practice: passing a  function call as opposed the function reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a solution I found was to use a higher order component. The HOC ended up looking like:

```
import React from "react";

const ChangeHeader = (func, WrappedComponent) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount = () => {
      func();
    };

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
};

export default ChangeHeader;
```

and then my routes ended up looking like:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={app} component={ChangeHeader(this.props.editableFalse, Dashboard)} />
    <Route path={clientList} component={ChangeHeader(this.props.editableFalse, ClientList)} />
    <Route exact path={settings} component={ChangeHeader(this.props.editableFalse, Settings)} />
    <Route path={businessInfo} component={ChangeHeader(this.props.editableTrue, BusinessInfo)} />
    <Route path={availability} component={ChangeHeader(this.props.editableFalse, Availability)} />
    <Route component={Error} />
</Switch>
```

This is ensuring I can pass any action to the component which will determine which header to render for that page (It also gets rid of the error in the console). This is very scalable and easy for new developers to follow the same pattern.